# how to build xml schema

Tags: xml, schema

is there any tool that support xml schema building

Answer (score 3):

I like [Liquid's XML Studio](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/) - it also comes as a free community edition.

Answer (score 2):

[oxygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/) should help you

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the best tools I've ever used: http://www.altova.com/xmlspy.html.  You can try it free for 30 days.  I work on a team that uses it all the time and it's well worth the money.

Comment: Great tools, steep price tag. ($1100 for the suite, $400 for XMLSpy alone)

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse offers also nice [XML Schema editor](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Introduction_to_the_XSD_Editor).

Answer (score 0):

IF what you meant was building schema by means of extracting and putting together elements, types, etc., available in other XML Schema files developed by third parties... then the above tools are not really a good fit. I would suggest [QTAssistant](http://paschidev.com/xsr.aspx)'s XML Schema Refactoring (XSR) - I am associated with it. It makes building XML Schema using content from XSDs (direcly, of via WSDLs) a very simple task. The XSR is designed from ground up for schema building, using a declarative approach. It also comes with a built-in XML Schema/WSDL/XML editor, sample generators, etc.